# Newly created Mercurial branch is not recognized by branches sub command

Tags: version-control, mercurial

If I create a branch using hg branch, a new branch is created.

```
λ hg branch new-branch
marked working directory as branch new-branch

λ hg identify -b
new-branch
```

Now, if I want to see all created branches, I don't see this branch.

```
λ hg branches -c
branch2                       13:3d2ed95e15b6
default                       10:556b09dd352b
test2                         12:f15ad58b843e (closed)
test1                         11:9fe883cc2d04 (closed)
```

Is there any branch subcommand switch to see this branch also ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that the branch you're on does not yet exist.  `hg branches` lists the branches that exist.  Your *proposed new commit* (in your working tree) will go onto the new branch `new-branch`, at which point `new-branch` *will* exist, because it will have a commit within it.  But until then it's more of a hypothetical branch: a branch that doesn't exist *yet*.

(Both `hg branch` and `hg summary` will tell you which branch you're on.)